# why this doesnt work? rewriting URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite this URL: `/PIT/employee/student-profile/2`

This works:

```bash
RewriteRule ^employee/([0-9]+) employee/student-profile.php?id=$1
```

This doesn't work:

```bash
RewriteRule ^employee/student-profile/([0-9]+) employee/student-profile.php?id=$1
```

I want it to be like this: `/PIT/employee/student-profile/2`

Comment: Please **do not** revert constructive edits that help others more easily see your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located and where is `student-profile.php` located?

Comment: my .htaccess is in PIT folder, student-profile.php is in employee folder which is also in PIT, PIT folder is my root folder or my project folder.
sorry for my late reply.